# Zend Newbie Question - How to pass info from Controller Action into View?

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller, action

On my controller I have the following Action:

```
public function indexAction()
{

  $teamDao = new TeamsDao();
  return $teamDao->showName(3);

}
```

So, I'm returning this team name, and my question is, how can I display this team name on the view ?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your controller:

```
$this->view->teamName = $teamDoa->showName(3);
```

And this in your view

```
<?php echo $this->teamName?>
```

Comment: Will this method work for all types of variables that we pass from controller to a view...